# Prompting/Displaying a Filter box for a specific column

Tags: excel, vba, vba7, vba6

I need a code which selects the column and displays the Filter box as shown in the below image("This is a filter dropdown which allows us to select the list of values").

I want a code which follows the following steps

1. Select column A
2. Prompts us the Filter box as shown in the below picture for us to manually select the data
3. Later, Run the rest part of the code

I have a code already in place but its prompts for an Input box with the values("Manually") to be entered in it. But this is not the one which I want.

Please find the below reference image and the code as-well.

```
Sub Filer_Box()

Dim uiDeptToShow As String

uiDeptToShow = Application.InputBox("Show which Department", Type:=2)
If uiDeptToShow = "False" Then Exit Sub: Rem Cancel pressed

Range("A1:M1").Select

Selection.AutoFilter

Selection.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=" & uiDeptToShow, Operator:=xlAnd

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Team, Can we have an update here?

Comment: Any update here?